# "message sent to deallocated instance" error with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

So when using "AFNetworking" in my project, i tried the very basic examples just to make sure it's working but i keep getting the following error:

```
[NSConcreteMutableData appendData:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x83aa8030
```

My code is:

```
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": username,
                             @"password": password,
                             @"comment_id": comment_id]};

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    [manager POST:url parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, id _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);            
    }];
```

The error occurs in the following function which is part of script: ([AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:] AFURLSessionManager.m:262)

```
#pragma mark - NSURLSessionDataDelegate

- (void)URLSession:(__unused NSURLSession *)session
      dataTask:(__unused NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
self.downloadProgress.totalUnitCount = dataTask.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive;
self.downloadProgress.completedUnitCount = dataTask.countOfBytesReceived;
[self.mutableData appendData:data];}
```

Comment: I do not believe the problem rests in the above code. We need [minimal, yet complete, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. Create a simple, yet complete, example that crashes.

Comment: Unrelated, you can simplify the instantiation of the manager: `AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store an instance of `AFHTTPSessionManager` in your class as a property. Something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPSessionManager *manager;
```

Then you should not see an error about the deallocated object, hopefully!
Else please post more context to the problem, so that I can help you with this.